# Textview no se añade a mi layout

Tags: android, c#, android-layout, xamarin, textview

Estoy tratando de añadir distintas `Textview`s a un layout que tengo creado, pero no hay manera. Hasta ahora esto siempre me ha funcionado, pero esta vez no encuentro donde está el fallo. Llevo varios días atascado con esto.

He hecho un [emcv](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en una App vacía para probar distintas cosas y no he encontrado solución, dejo el layout y la clase principal esperando que alguien vea algo que yo no, también alguna captura de inspección de variables.

Como digo, el problema es que no consigo añadir `Textview` al `Linearlayout` por código.

## MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        addviews();
    }

    void addviews()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(MainActivity.LayoutInflaterService);
        View lIntrusion = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, null);

        LinearLayout layout = lIntrusion.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.lista);
        addlinearlayout(layout);
    }

    void addlinearlayout(LinearLayout lista)
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TextView texto = new TextView(this);
            texto.LayoutParameters = lp;
            texto.Text = i + "Esta funcionando";
            lista.AddView(texto);
        }
    }
```

## activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <!--Layout 1-->
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/layout1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#FDF6E9"
      android:weightSum="22">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/layout11"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/image1" />
      <EditText
          android:layout_weight="3"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:hint="Zona a buscar..."
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/edittext1" />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:id="@+id/image2"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/scroll1">
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/lista" />
    </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

## Captura del Layout, el recuadro azul es donde debería de cargar la lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Inspección de la variable: `lista` del método `addlinearlayout(LinearLayout lista)`

Aquí se puede ver que los elementos se están añadiendo en el layout, pero en la App no aparecen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Actualizo 1

Si en vez de meter un `textview` por código en `ScrollView` cambio el `axml` y pongo un `textview` aparece, pero el `linearlayout` que hay en `ScrollView` no se dibuja, para probar esto he probado a cambiar el background-color a verde y no sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas usar `LayoutInflater` en `addviews`, ese es el problema principal.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(MainActivity.LayoutInflaterService);

 View lIntrusion = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, null);

 LinearLayout layout = lIntrusion.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.lista);
```

Cámbialo por esto:

```
 LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.lista);
addlinearlayout(layout);
```

Creo que es ahí dónde esté el problema.

Esta probado y funcionando. Saludos

Comment: Al final si funciona, el problema está en usar inflater