# ¿Qué es y qué hace LayoutInflater?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, layout

Llevo poco más de un mes desarrollando en `Xamarin`, y pese a haber estudiado `Android`, hasta ahora no he tenido la oportunidad, o más bien, la necesidad de usar `LayoutInflater`.

Tuve hace poco un problema usando, o abusando de esta característica. Resuelto en esta pregunta: [Textview no se añade a mi layout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234428/textview-no-se-a%C3%B1ade-a-mi-layout), el problema venía por usar el LayoutInflater cuando no debía.

He leído la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) y en esta pone que *instancia un layout xml a su `view` correspondiente*. Lo que me lleva a pensar que cuando *"inflo"* un layout estoy creando un layout vacío a partir de ese XML.

En [este articulo](http://www.mhjaso.com/blog/inflater/) comparan un `Layoutinflater` con un hinchador de playa, entiendo la metáfora que dentro va el `XML` como gas y la pelota de playa sería la variable tipo `vista`/`View` dónde se carga ese `XML`

**¿Esto es así?** Sé que puede parecer sencillo, pero hay algo que me chirría en todo esto.

¿Que ventajas puede tener? ¿Cuando me puede convenir más usar `Layoutinflater` que asignar a una variable un `FindViewById()` y pasar directamente el layout?

Comment: Es exactamente lo que acabas de describir. el inflate es solo una instancia del Layout XML, para poder usarlo por ejemplo en Dialogs, en mi caso lo uso exclusivamente para Dialogs o Adapters para crear listas.

Comment: @TheVicShow pues vaya... pensé que era algo más complicado .. :S

Comment: No en realidad, tal como dices, si creas un XML pero lo quieres mostrar en un Dialog, para acceder a sus propiedades debes "inflar" la vista (XML) y ya con la instancia accedes a las propiedades por ejemplo `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.XMLLayout, container, false);` y para acceder por ejemplo a un boton que este dentro solo es `rootView.findViewById(R.id.boton);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Te refieres a el [LayoutInflater](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/), en realidad inflater es el nombre de la variable que generalmente es usada para inflar un layout en Android:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
 var layout = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_elemento, layoutImages) as LinearLayout;
```

Para establecer una diferencia es necesario conocer las definiciones:

> **[LayoutInflater](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/)** Crea una instancia de un archivo XML de diseño en
>   sus objetos de vista correspondientes. Nunca se usa directamente. En
>   su lugar, usar
>   `Context.getSystemService(Class)` para recuperar una instancia de
>   [LayoutInflater](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/)  estándar que ya está conectada al contexto actual
>   y configurada correctamente para el dispositivo en el que se está
>   ejecutando.
>
> **[FindViewById()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.FindViewById/)** Busca la primera vista descendiente con la ID
>   dada, la vista en sí misma si la ID coincide, o nula si
>   la ID no es válida (<0) o si no hay una vista coincidente en la
>   jerarquía.

---

Con respecto a tus preguntas:

> comparan un Layoutinflater con un hinchador de playa, entiendo la
>   metáfora que dentro va el XML como gas y la pelota de playa sería la
>   variable tipo vista/View dónde se carga ese XML
>
> ¿Esto es así? Sé que puede parecer sencillo, pero hay algo que me
>   chirría en todo esto.

Es buena comparación, el "hinchador" infla el layout playa:

```
 View view =  LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_playa, null);
```

pero dentro de esta vista (layout_playa) puedes encontrar elementos como `pelota`, `sombrilla`, `lentes_sol`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pelota"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sombrilla"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lentes_sol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout >
```

Para acceder a estos elementos buscas en la vista que previamente inflaste mediante sus id haciendo uso de **[FindViewById()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.FindViewById/)**, ya que estos elementos se encuentran dentro de la vista :

```
 View view =  LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_playa, null);
 ImageView img_pelota = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.pelota);
 TextView tv_sombrilla = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sombrilla);
 TextView tv_lentes = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lentes_sol);
```

Es importante que las referencias de las vistas que obtengas mediante **[FindViewById()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.FindViewById/)** deben existir, de otra forma obtendrías valores null.

---

> ¿Que ventajas puede tener? ¿Cuando me puede convenir más usar
>   Layoutinflater que asignar a una variable un FindViewById() y pasar
>   directamente el layout?

En realidad su uso es diferente, **[LayoutInflater](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/)** crea una instancia de un archivo XML de diseño en sus objetos de vista correspondientes y esta vista no necesita existir en el layout que de tu actividad pero si en los recursos mientras que para usar **[FindViewById()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.FindViewById/)** se usa para buscar vistas que se encuentran en un layout previamente inflado :

Otro ejemplo de **[LayoutInflater](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/)** imagina que tienes que "inflar" un tipo de celda cuando la celda de tu listado es par y otro tipo cuando es impar:

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

```
   View view = convertView;
   if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
       view  =  LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_par, null);
    } else {
       view  =  LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_impar, null);
    }

   }

    return view ;
}
```

como ejemplo de **[FindViewById()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.FindViewById/)**, buscas en dentro de un layout (`layout_app`) la referencia de una vista (`TextView`) mediante su id (`Resource.Id.tv_titulo`) y modificas alguna propiedad, en este caso asignas un texto.

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

       View view = convertView;
       if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new   
           view  =  LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_par, null);
           TextView tv_sombrilla = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sombrilla);

        tv_sombrilla.SetText("Aplicación Aritzbn");  
       }

        return view ;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la clase profe ;)

Answer (score 7):

El [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater), básicamente lo que hace es tener una *referencia/instanciar* un *layout axml* para poder utilizar las vistas dentro del mismo. Cuando vas a cargar contenido en una pantalla, por ejemplo, una `Activity`, haces `SetContentView` para indicar que el contenido de esa pantalla apunta a un layout en específico. Esto quiere decir, que las referencias que vayas a buscar haciendo `FindViewById` en esa **Activity**, solo deben estar adjuntas a ese layout que has cargado.

Normalmente, la vista principal de un Layout es un [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) (por ejemplo, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, etc...), un layout tipo padre que contiene hijos, por lo que si intentas hacer `FindViewById` de una vista o hijo que no pertenezca a ese [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) , por ejemplo, que esté en otro *layout axml* diferente al que se cargó para una pantalla o `Activity` específica, entonces este te devolverá una referencia `null`.

Pongamos el siguiente ejemplo: digamos que quieres crear diferentes pantallas. Utilizando un mismo layout que contiene un `Button` con el id `button` y un `TextView` con el id `textView`. Hacer esto vía axml tienes muchas alternativas, como utilizar la etiqueta [include](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts). Sin embargo, si quieres hacerlo programáticamente, aquí debes utilizar LayoutInflater.

Por ejemplo: `Xamarin.Android (C#)`, utilizando [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) en un `Activity`:

```
// Esta es la referencia que tiene el Button y el TextView
View layoutReutilizable = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_reutilizable, null);

// Esta es la referencia a la vista de tu Activity donde quieres cargar el layout
View layoutPadre = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.llContainer));
layoutPadre.AddView(layoutReutilizable);
```

De esta forma ya tienes cargado ese layout dentro de tu `LinearLayout`. Si quieres acceder a ese `Button` y el `TextView` para modificarlos, simplemente puedes hacer:

```
Button button = layoutReutilizable.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
TextView textView = layoutReutilizable.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.textView);
```

y ya puedes customizarlo y asignarle las propiedades que quieras.