# "¿Se puede instanciar objetos de una clase sin el operador New"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una duda la cual no podría esclarecer, debido a que veo en muchos tutoriales de Android Studio hacerlo, pero sin una explicación alguna, tengo entendido que hay algunos objetos de algunas clases que pueden instanciar sin el operador new, como la clase String

Ya que suelo ver

```
String nombre = "Pedro"
```

en vez de poner

```
String nombre = new String ("Pedro")
```

El codigo es el siguiente en un MainActivity basico de Android donde trato de referenciar etiquetas

```
package com.example.miaplicacion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editName,editAge;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
    editAge=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);

}
```

Al inicializar los objetos editName y editText, por que no instancio los objetos antes con el operador new ? colocando ejm:

```
 editName = new EditText ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name));
```

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235380/qu%c3%a9-es-y-qu%c3%a9-hace-layoutinflater

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario instanciar el caso que propones:

```
editName = new EditText ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText Name));
```

Ya que lo que estas haciendo con el findviewbyid es recoger el objeto de la vista XML es una forma de mapeo para que la actividad sepa cuales son los objetos del XML

```
editName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
```

Comment: Lo que dices es verdad a medias. En realidad, internamente, el framework va a instanciar el objeto por reflexión.

Answer (score 1):

> Al inicializar los objetos editName y editText, por que no instancio
>   los objetos antes con el operador new ?
>   Ejemplo: `editName = new EditText ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name));`

La respuesta es que en este caso no es necesario instanciarlos ya que los objetos ya existen cuando es inflado el layout que los contiene, en este caso `activity_main.xml` que es cargado mediante `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Lo que realizas mediante el método `findViewById(...)` es obtener una referencia de ese objeto.

---

Si el objeto `EditText` no se encontrara en el layout, entonces crearías una instancia del objeto y lo agregarías al layout, ejemplo:

```
EditText editName = new EditText(getContext());
editName.setTextSize(12);
editName.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
//Se agrega EditText al layout
linearLayout.addView(editName);
```